# The blonde doll in the Doctor's pocket

Tags: doctor-who

In the episode "Cold War", one of the things taken from the Doctor when he is searched, is a blonde doll ("Barbie" type).  Was that a passing joke, (referencing Rose maybe?) or was it significant in this episode?  Or is it one of those things that becomes significant later as the series goes on?

Comment: Wasn't he given the Barbie in a previous season by a child?

Comment: Can you remember which episode? I couldn't recall seeing it before.

Comment: sorry, I don't recall. Was fairly recently (for American audiences at least).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought/assumed it was just a one-off gag, especially since I haven't read anything anywhere else to indicate otherwise. But, there's nothing preventing the writers from revisiting this detail at a later time (as they seem to tend to do).

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much what I thought, just wondered if anyone had seen something I'd missed. As you say, could be significant later, could be a throwaway joke.